# sql concatenate columns if one or more columns is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I  have a table that looks something like this:

```
BuildingID | RouterType | RouterPort | RouterInstaller | Notes
-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+-------
282        | Linksys    | 1990       | Super           | NULL
307        | Sonic Wall | NULL       | Greg            | NULL
311        | NULL       | NULL       | NULL            | NULL
```

I would like the Notes column to be the concatenation of the 2nd 3rd and 4th columns only if the column is not null.

```
line 1: Router Type: Linksys Router Port: 1990 Router Installer: Super
line 2: Router Type: Sonic Wall Router Installer: Greg
line 3: NULL
```

Also the word 'Router Type:' should only come in if the value of Router type is not null etc.

I am pretty new to SQL - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's `COALESCE(column, '')` to change NULLs to empty strings.

Comment: What's your DB?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: There's no reason to actually store the concatenated data in a column, simply do it in a Select (View): `COALESCE('RouterType: '|| RouterType ||',' , '')`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select case when [Note] = '' then null else Note from (
    select BulidingId,
            case when RouterType is null then '' else 'Router Type: ' + RouterType + '; '+
            case when RouterPort is null then '' else 'Router Port: ' + RouterPort + '; '+
            case when RouterInstaller is null then '' else 'Router Port: ' + RouterInstaller + '; '+
            case when Notes is null then '' else 'Notes: ' + Notes + '; ' [Note]
    from MY_TABLE
) a
```

Comment: @goldie Accept the answer if it helped you solving your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it by combining Coalesce and Concat.  The column names are added as labels to the column values.

```
select COALESCE(Notes, COALESCE(CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT('RouterType: ',RouterType),''), 
                       COALESCE(CONCAT(' RouterPort: ',RouterPort ),''),
                       COALESCE(CONCAT(' RouterInstaller: ',RouterInstaller),'')), NULL)) as Notes
from yourTable;
```

Comment: this solution shows for line 2:  "Router Type: Linksys Router Port: Router Installer: Greg". I don't want Router Port: to show up in this case because RouterPort is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this update statement:

```
DECLARE @TEMP_TABLE TABLE (
    BUILDING_ID INT,
    ROUTER_TYPE VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    PORT INT NULL,
    ROUTER_INSTALLER VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    NOTES VARCHAR(1000) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE VALUES(1,'Linksys Router', 1990, 'Super', NULL)
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE VALUES(2,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

UPDATE @TEMP_TABLE 
SET NOTES = COALESCE(' Router type: ' + ROUTER_TYPE,'') + COALESCE(' Port: ' + CAST(PORT AS VARCHAR),'') + COALESCE(' Router installer: ' + ROUTER_INSTALLER,'')
WHERE ROUTER_TYPE IS NOT NULL OR PORT IS NOT NULL OR ROUTER_INSTALLER IS NOT NULL

SELECT * FROM @TEMP_TABLE
```

Comment: Replace the update above with this one:

    UPDATE @TEMP_TABLE

    SET NOTES = COALESCE(' Router type: ' + ROUTER_TYPE,'') + COALESCE(' Port: ' + CAST(PORT AS VARCHAR),'') + COALESCE(' Router installer: ' + ROUTER_INSTALLER,'')

    WHERE ROUTER_TYPE IS NOT NULL OR PORT IS NOT NULL OR ROUTER_INSTALLER IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try this select query, i think it will help you:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (
  COL2 IS NOT NULL 
   AND COL3 IS NOT NULL 
   AND  COL4 IS NOT NULL )
    THEN 
        CONCAT(COL2,' ', COL3,' ', COL4) END as ConcatedData,
     * from YOUR_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the spacing correct, I recommend:

```
select stuff(coalesce(' RouterType: ' + RouterType), '') +
             coalesce(' RouterPort: ' + RouterPort ), '') +
             coalesce(' RouterInstaller: ', RouterInstaller), ''),
             1, 1, ''
            ) as Notes
from t;
```

In an `update`:

```
update t
    set notes = stuff(coalesce(' RouterType: ' + RouterType), '') +
                      coalesce(' RouterPort: ' + RouterPort ), '') +
                      coalesce(' RouterInstaller: ', RouterInstaller), ''),
                      1, 1, ''
                     );
```

Note:  This will not put in a `NULL` value, instead using an empty string.  That is easily fixed -- if it is a problem:

```
update t
    set notes = nullif(stuff(coalesce(' RouterType: ' + RouterType), '') +
                             coalesce(' RouterPort: ' + RouterPort ), '') +
                             coalesce(' RouterInstaller: ', RouterInstaller), ''),
                             1, 1, ''
                            ), ''
                      )
```